# Database design for efficient retrieval

Tags: database-design, relational-database

This was one of my interview questions. There is a huge database which is going to hold millions of employee records. I should be able to efficiently query based on any fields like first name, last name, age, location etc and the results should be retrieved quickly. How would you go about  designing the database. I answered based on indexing etc , but the interview was not satisfied. Any suggestions as to how this design is actually done ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about context of the question, but as far as I understand you were asked about data modeling, not about 'pure' optimization of existing database/queries.

I'd go with the following approach. An enterprise can have 'operational database' or OLTP which is optimized for entering new data (minimal set of indexes, highly normalized), and 'decision-support database' (data warehouse, OLAP systems) which has lots of redundancy from normalization perspective, but allows you to search by different criteria very fast. Modeling data warehouse from OLTP system is quite a big topic and requires deep understanding of business needs.

To answer the question about searching through employees I'd propose to build a simple star schema (where each search condition represented by a dimension table). Then appropriate technique like indexing, partitioning, materialized view may be added on top of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Those requirements suggest considering a key-value store to me rather than a traditional SQL database.

A key-value store will allow you to do relatively unstructured query (i.e. you don't need to define the schema ahead of time) and is designed for very fast reads.

Examples:

- Redis
- Casandra
- Couch
- MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the interviewer wanted one key word : `normalisation`

All the indices in the world aren't going to help an in-normalised database - perhaps the 'employee records' in question contained name, address... on each and every record and the records were projects, vacation days, sick days, etc.

The clue, I believe, is in 'millions of' 'employee' records. Even the biggest government departments don't have 'millions of' employees, so the database isn't normalised.